# Easy Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a control which has a button named "btn1", and I want to change it's contents through a dependency property in xaml, like this:

```
<UserControl:UserControl1 ButtonContents="Something"/>
```

Here's what I have:

```
Public Class UserControl1 
    Public Shared ReadOnly ButtonContentsProperty As DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonContents",
                                    GetType(String),
                                    GetType(UserControl.UserControl1))

    Public Property ButtonContents() As Boolean
        Get
            Return GetValue(ButtonContentsProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            SetValue(ButtonContentsProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

But how can the dependency property know what to do?

Comment: Add a PropertyChangedCallback and in the static callback event handler you can call a private method on sender which in turn sets the `Content`. Otherwise, depending on your situation, you might be able to bind it

Comment: There's one more way of doing that (which I personally prefer) - bind your DP to a Content property of your button and use the converter:) In actual fact you can use the behavior on a button side which will give you full access to the whole button, not just its Content property. Just let us know and I'll craft a small sample.

Comment: @Dmitry can you show me an example?

Comment: Could you give us some samples of what your button's content might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is based upon the following approach - button's content gets defined as a resource belonging to the button itself. Unfortunately ResourceKey is not a DP and hence cannot be bound, we created an attached property BindiableResourceKey which subsistutes for that. The user control has a property ButtonLook of string type which holds the name of the resource to be used as button's content. If you need to implement more complex linking logic just extend the attached property value changed handler.

Here's the code:

Part1 - User Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ButtonContentBinding.AControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" 
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonContentBinding">
    <Grid>
        <Button local:BindableResourceControl.ResourceKey="{Binding ButtonLook}">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Rectangle x:Key="BlueRectangle"
                    Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Blue" />
                <Rectangle x:Key="GreenRectangle"
                    Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Green" />
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Part 2 - Attached Property:

```
public class BindableResourceControl : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourceKeyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ResourceKey",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(BindableResourceControl),
            new PropertyMetadata((x, y) =>
            {
                ContentControl contentControl = x as ContentControl;

                if (x != null)
                {
                    contentControl.Content = contentControl.Resources[y.NewValue];
                }
            }));

        public static void SetResourceKey(DependencyObject x, string y)
        {
            x.SetValue(BindableResourceControl.ResourceKeyProperty, y);
        }

        public static string GetResourceKey(DependencyObject x)
        {
            return (string)x.GetValue(BindableResourceControl.ResourceKeyProperty);
        }
    }
```

Part 3 - Consumer:

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonContentBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ButtonContentBinding">
    <Grid>
        <my:AControl ButtonLook="GreenRectangle"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0"      
                x:Name="aControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Height="200" Width="200" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you register the property, you can also define a PropertyChangedCallback method where you can decide what to do when the property changes. 
More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#prerequisites) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx#Coerce_Value_Callbacks_and_Property_Changed_Events).

Answer (score 0):

I would usually bind the value in the UserControl's XAML, e.g.

```
<UserControl ...
             Name="control">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Button Content="{Binding ButtonContents, ElementName=control}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```